# ItunesConnect : new ipa version with os restrictions?

Tags: ios, target, ipa, device

can someone confirm to me that it is not possible to add new version of an ipa on itunes connect, which is more restrictive in target devices than the first version ?

First version of my app is available for iOS 3 and more
I would reduces the OS to iOS 6 and more..

I know that it was impossible, but is it always like this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't reduce device features (e.g. you can't exclude devices without cameras), but you can reduce supported iOS versions.
Few days ago I submitted the app that reduced minimum iOS version from iOS5.X to iOS6.X